# Why is separate resource file generated after saving?

Tags: visual-studio

Before modifying a resource file, it looks like this in VS.NET (2013):

```
Strings.resx
  Strings.Designer.cs
```

After saving, it looks like this:

```
Strings.resx
  Strings.Designer.cs
  Strings1.Designer.cs
```

If I try to run the project, I get an error that Strings already exist.  I have to then delete Strings.Designer.cs and rename Strings1.Designer.cs to Strings.Designer.cs.

Then I have to unload the project and modify those references in the project file XML.  Then reload and all is well until I modify again.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you save the file while debugging or something like that? I don't know actually I'm just trying to guess.

Comment: No - I was running the app.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the binaries and recompile?

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio can't access to `Strings.Designer.cs` and create a new file. Whatever the reason is, I think you should delete the file and recreate from scratch. I don't have any further idea.

Comment: Meant I "wasn't" running the app.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I deleted my old resource file and created a new resource file with same name and content. Now it is working fine.

So, delete the `Strings.resx` file and create a new file with the same name that is `Strings.resx`

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from this link [Generating *.Designer.cs from .resx](https://github.community/t/generating-designer-cs-from-resx/126146/2).

Basically, you need to:

1. Right-click on your project and click **Unload**.
2. Then right-click again and click on **Edit** on your project.
3. Find the string **<LastGenOutput>** and change the entry to whatever you want.

For example, I need to generate `Strings.Designer.cs`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="App_GlobalResources\Strings.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>Strings.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="App_GlobalResources\Strings.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Strings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

I hope this post can help someone in the future.

Cheers